# Angular+Bootstrap : Table designing

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with several features I want to implement:

- I want a fixed table header so I can scroll down while still be able to see the header as I go through the data.
- I want my table to be as large as it can be => no overflow-x
- My columns can be from different sizes, yet the header must be aligned.
- My < td > have to restrain from a max-height, and add a scrollbar inside the td.

Are these even possible ? Because I tried several inconclusives solutions =(

If I separate the header from the table, it'll mess up the width of the columns header.

```
.test {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

> If you are using visible for either overflow-x or overflow-y and something other than visible for the other. The visible value is interpreted as auto.

And these won't work:

- [Fixed header table in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362077/fixed-header-table-in-angularjs)
- [Twitter bootstrap scrollable table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420168/twitter-bootstrap-scrollable-table)
- http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

EDIT @[Merijn DK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2177057/merijn-dk):

```
<!-- html -->
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-show="column.show" ng-style="column.style">
                {{ column.label }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in results">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-show="column.show" ng-style="column.style" ng-bind-html="item.data | unsafe">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

//Javascript
.filter('unsafe', function($sce, $rootScope) {
     return function(html) {
         return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
     };
 });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The question isn't meant to ask people to code for me. I already have the table, the data is formatted perfectly. It's about design (you can look the title). You say it's possible, please, show me. I've search a lot and I'm just tired trying always the same methods that only work for one case. I've given examples I tried.

Comment: thanx your getting closer. can you also post the css which styles your header?

Comment: im quite sure http://www.fixedheadertable.com/ would do the trick btw. are you sure you tried that right? had you included jquery etc?

Comment: None at the moment, since it's all part of bootstrap.
For the test, I just tried separating the head from the body. Since the column width are differents for each other, it messes up with the alignment from the body.
The thing is every solutions I got separatly messes with another feature I want to implement on the table.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is included. Yet the thing is : the data display in the body is done by ng-bind-html + unsafe filter. So fixedheadertable is cool unless you need to display complexe data.

Comment: aah oke. I understand. could you try to remake your page in jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ you can select angularJs is the left dropdown. thanx in advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3JA4J/4/

I don't understand how it is supposed to work.

Comment: oke I dont understand what you're trying to achieve now. your jsfiddle is not a menu but a table right? maybe the answare below can help you?

Comment: I never said it was a menu. I don't understand how JSFiddle is supposed to work with angular.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3JA4J/6/ here is my updated version with a fixed header. tho you should include the style in the angular css file. hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Well the problem with your solution is that it "works" with one column, if you add several more with different widths, you'll have a messed up table.

Comment: well then I think you have to look at the solution below. Im quite sure it could fic your problem with a little tweeking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found a nice plugin that allows floating or fixed theads in various ways. [Just look at the awesome demos here](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/)

Now you need to implement that in angular. I made a very quick and imperfect directive which could be improved a lot: (allready improved by @spades himself, THX for being awesome!)

```
plunker.directive('thead', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem) {
        window.onscroll = function() {
            elem.floatThead({
                scrollingTop: 45,
            });
            elem.floatThead('reflow');
        }
    }
  };
})
```

You can tryout the various options by adding them here:

```
elem.floatThead(additionaloptions);
```

Just add the directive your html:

```
  <table thead>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>111</td>
      </tr> ...
```

Find a complete plunker (with example for window scrolling) [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AflhbM9jGgf30fQnc0Y2?p=preview) (of course this could also happen in container, just look at the floatThead homepage)

Note that you should open the preview in a new window (blue x on the top right side) and size its height until a scrollbar shows up.

Comment: I almost got it right : http://imgur.com/HOPDPdN&EgPHLxU#1
But when I scroll down : http://imgur.com/HOPDPdN&EgPHLxU#0

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell where this is coming from without your final code. Here is another plunker I made that corellates more to your initial question http://plnkr.co/edit/pbfDxTutsIaaPkVYw8tR?p=preview. (I could not implement safehtml for now). But in general it works. Maybe play around with the options of the jquery plugin. As i said, I did not write it, but found it some days ago on DailyJS and thought: Hey, this may be usefull some day:-) I will leave off work for now and look back at your forecomings tomorrow. Nice evening:-)

Comment: Looks awesome, why does it not work on your page? I bet you tell me tomorrow. Good Luck!

Comment: Well the safehtml isn't complicated and it works, but if you look closely to my plnkr, I just updated it, you can see that it doesn't scroll =(

Comment: What browser (version also) are you using ?

Comment: FF 27.01 - Really, I'm about to leave the office now. Lets continue tomorrow.

Comment: No problem ^^ don't feel obligated to answer me immediately !
I'll keep digging.

Comment: I don't understand, I use the very same version of Firefox, and the thing that messes up the design seems to be Firebug ...

Comment: I think I found the glitch : I have to change the window size to enable the correct floatTHead. I don't understand why though.

Comment: @mainguy The OP [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4091138) to your answer that got rejected. Maybe you want to change your post to incorporate it somehow.

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm on sick leave today cuz i caught a friggin cold. Cant't actualy follow this discussion for now, can't concentrat while waiting for my head to burst. Have checked the issue yesterday evening and found out that my directive does not work on Chrome and (for sure) not in IE. So for now, if @Spades found a solution that works, it's fine for me if he tells it to other users that might need it. I'm out for the count by now... So Sorry...

Comment: Thank you @mainguy. Get better !
About the modification : the settimeout is useless, so I put a condition that watches the scrolling : If the user need to scroll, then the floatThead is activated, else, it isn't.